# How to sum the value and retrieve the result using if condition- using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to sum every time and check with if condition. If condition matches I want the get the created date of the final matched row.

```
+------------+----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|       id   | EMAIL                            | created    | Amt    |
+------------+----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|         61 | abc@gmail.com                    | 1514909390 |  57.00 |
|         25 | xyz@gmail.com                    | 1515534837 | 360.00 |
|         36 | zccc@abv.com                     | 1515645391 | 240.00 |
|         22 | vv@aa.com                        | 1516419622 | 320.40 |
|         48 | aa@xyz.com                       | 1516706121 | 240.00 |
+------------+----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

I try this query but I'm not getting the solution...

```
select
    sum(a.amount) as amt,
    if(sum(a.amount)>8000,slp.sal_time,0) as Amt_exceed_date
from employee a
join emp_user u
    on a.cmp_id=u.user_id
left join emp_sal as slp
    on slp.user_id=a.cmp_id
where
order by slp.sal_time;
```

Comment: Your query has multiple problems, to the point where I can't really guess an answer.  Maybe show us sample data, the expected output, and then describe the logic to us.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat like row wise sum

```
select e.*,(
  select sum(Amt)
  from employee
  where created <= e.created
) row_wise_sum
from employee e
having row_wise_sum < 800
order by e.created
desc limit 1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5ed49/10)

Comment: Hi, @M Khalid Junaid I tried but my need is to be.. if (sum(amt) >500)  then get the created date of the current row.

Comment: @SarathVenkat Like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5ed49/31, Can you include the expected output in your question ?

Comment: Yes, I understood @M Khalid Junaid but you are using condition <=e.created_time but I have more no.of value in my database. Is there any other condition to sum each row

Comment: The above one is the result, In that, i need each row need to be the sum. Whatever you did is correct but I have lots of created_time in my database. If I put the condition that throws the wrong result.